# PHPMailer Could not instantiate mail function abount Attachment

Tags: php, email

I created a mail form, and it's works, but if I attach more then 10 pdfs I got this error :

```
Errore durante l'invio : Could not instantiate mail function.
```

I googled but nothing about the maximum size of attachment neither about maximum mail size, what can I do? Someone can help me please?

I use [this one](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

And this is a part of code

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

                    $body = $_POST['message'];

                    //$mail->AddReplyTo('replyto@email.com', 'Reply to name'); 
                    //$mail->SetFrom('mailbox@email.com', 'Mailbox name');

                    $address = $_POST['email'];

                    $mail->AddAddress($_POST['email'], $_POST['to']);
                    $mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
                    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

                    foreach($_POST['pdfs'] as $selected){
                        $mail->AddAttachment($selected); 
                    }

                    if(!$mail->Send()) {
                      echo '<p class="text-left text-danger">Errore durante l\'invio : ' . $mail->ErrorInfo .'</p>'; 
                    } else {
                      echo '<p class="text-left text-success"> Messaggio inviato</p>';
                    }
                } else echo '<p class="text-left text-danger">Nessun pdf selezionato</p>';
```

Comment: Kindly, include classes at the top.

Comment: I did it lol,read better i Said the code works

Answer (score -2):

```
    <?php
    include "class.phpmailer.php";
    include "class.smtp.php";

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $body = $_POST['message'];

    //$mail->AddReplyTo('replyto@email.com', 'Reply to name'); 
    //$mail->SetFrom('mailbox@email.com', 'Mailbox name');

    $address = $_POST['email'];

    $mail->AddAddress($_POST['email'], $_POST['to']);
    $mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    foreach($_POST['pdfs'] as $selected){
    $mail->AddAttachment($selected); 
    }

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo '<p class="text-left text-danger">Errore durante l\'invio : ' . $mail->ErrorInfo .'</p>'; 
    } else {
    echo '<p class="text-left text-success"> Messaggio inviato</p>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: At the top, I have included phpmailer classes, and from the bottom, I have removed last ELSE statement as it was followed by ELSE rather than ELSE IF. Are you getting me?

Comment: I do, but I can't say the same for anyone who doesn't bother reading the comments, which could be the OP… *hint hint that should be part of the answer*

Comment: Sorry bro, not getting your point. Can you please elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: I'm saying that you should edit the contents of [this comment](/questions/41638070/phpmailer-could-not-instantiate-mail-function-abount-attachment/41638224?noredirect=1#comment70476286_41638224) into your answer because not everyone reads the comments.

Comment: What your code is for? Why did you remove the ifs? This never will work for my solution.My question was about the limit of the mail size or file attachment